# LTSP fat clients not connecting to internet in proxy DHCP mode

Tags: networking, routing, ltsp

My current setup is modem to router. Router(10.10.10.0/24) to virtual server via enp8s1. Virtual machine running pfsense as a DHCP server via enp3s0(a second nic in the server)  a network 192.168.67.0/24. Another virtual computer, same server, setup with LTSP with ubuntu mate. I followed the steps on the LTSP.org page to the letter and the fat clients aren't getting internet. Now the 192 network gets internet. Every computer (besides the fat clients) gets an IP, and connects fine. No issue. The LTSP server is running in proxy mode (letting the pfsense router do all the IP routing stuff) and gets internet, but the fat clients aren't connecting to the internet. Does anyone know how to get the clients connected? If not, any suggestions?

The clients cannot ping the modem, 192.168.0.1 or the first router 10.10.10.1

Comment: For better reproducibility of the problem consider to create LTSP server and clients using VirtualBox (something like [this article](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients)). As I wrote before - I did not tried 2 NIC configuration, so I can't help to debug this problem. For me proxyDHCP method is reliable and comfortable.

Comment: @N0rbert I swear you help me everytime i ask a question here. I setit up sort of the way you suggested. I followed (http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Installation/Ubuntu) to the letter. (copy paste) I preffered proxyDHCP cause i find it more realiable as well. I was working before on the server its self, but that crashed (bac=d hard drive) so I set it up as a vm instead. Its using the pfsense vm as a dhcp, which is pushing internet to all devices, not the ltsp clients. Think it might be a issue with setting it up from the start, or the fact that its a vm on a server (From 2003 btw)?

Comment: I can't now but ill update the post with the server specs and vm specs when I can.